# mysql trigger, let trigger recalculate throug whole table after correction of errors

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am using a trigger with some calculation on table A to fill a table B with these calculated values.
Due to crash table A was filled here and there with faulty values, so the calculations result put in table B are here and there not correct.

How can I go through all the rows (in a certain range)  and let the trigger recalculate the values and overwrite them in table B.

table A have values of elec meter and gas meter  every 5 minutes.
There are about 700 entries wrong.

any suggestion would be aprechiated, thanks

Comment: update the values to the correct values and the trigger should work automatically.  That is how triggers work.

Comment: yep - was going to suggest update yourtable set pk=pk to fire off the triggers.  but my guess it that it is an insert trigger and the logic is probably wrong for this effort.  you should post your trigger code.

Comment: I deleted the rows with the faulty values. And want to rebuild the table with use of the trigger. so the "to be rebuild" values are in the past.

Comment: Still no one who can give me the answer, maybe I am not clear. I want to go back in time with the trigger for example 2 months and from that point in time go up and let the trigger recalc the outputs. IS THIS POSSIBLE?

Answer (score 0):

the trigger contents is and initiated after table A update:

BEGIN
SELECT max(`ElectraHighP1` + `ElectraLowP1`) - min(`ElectraHighP1` + `ElectraLowP1`) FROM `data_rr` WHERE DATE (FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = curdate() INTO @var1;
SELECT max(`SolarHighP1` + `SolarLowP1`) - min(`SolarHighP1` + `SolarLowP1`) FROM `data_rr` WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = curdate() INTO @var2;
SELECT max(`GasConsumedTotalP1`) - min(`GasConsumedTotalP1`) FROM `data_rr` WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = curdate() INTO @var3;
INSERT INTO `DayData` (`ElectraUsedToday`, `SolarDeliveryToday`, `GasConsumedToday` ) VALUES (@var1, @var2,@var3);
END

Calculates the dayvalues of energy tables.